Expo 52 - Android - Invalid Data safety form, Device ID
Submitting my Android app(s) to Google Play after updating to Expo 52 has resulted in a rejection from Google:
Invalid Data safety form

...We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

...Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)

We're not collecting it in our code, so this must have been introduced by the Expo 52.0.0 sdk.
Has anyone else run into this?? Is this expected? I can't imagine its ok for Expo to be collecting our users' device IDs.
